# Flash development on MacOSX

Tags: flash

I'm familiar with C/C++/Scheme/Java/OpenGL/TCP/IP.

I need to learn how to build a tile based / platform flash engine.

What tools should I be using?

What books should I buy?

I strongly prefer tools that let me do things programatically rather than through a graphical UI.

Answer (score 0):

Must confess, I only work *with* Flash developers, so this is a bit second hand. That said, hopefully it'll provide some leads until someone with more hands on knowledge chimes in.

Whilst there are [open source tools available](http://www.ipov.net/blog/2009/09/flash-dev-environment-with-open-source-tools/), it may prove easier (at least initially) to use Adobe's Flash Professional development environment.

If you focus on [ActionScript 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html), you'll find you can achieve pretty much everything programatically rather than having to use the traditional timeline style editing tools.

Answer (score 0):

I use [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) with [Simon Gregory's ActionScript add-on](http://github.com/simongregory/actionscript3-tmbundle/) for coding and Adobe Flash CS4 IDE for handling assets and for publishing/compiling.

[Flex Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) is another option, it is an Eclips based editor, and can be used for Flash/ActionScript development without including the Flex framework in the resulting swf.